# Vertical align of flexbox childs's child

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I [have](https://jsfiddle.net/f9h3tdp3/) a flexbox container with `header`, `footer` and a `content`. Using flexbox is no problem for me to stretch `content` so that it takes all available vertical space (colored green).

But I cannot center vertically all that is inside `content` after. I was first thinking to do the same flexbox approach, but it fails. In my example, basically, the red area must take all space that green area takes, and the text should be centered vertically and horizontally inside green area.

What do I miss?

Comment: I actually see it aligned. The text inside the red div is perfectly aligned, What's the problem?

Comment: it is not in the center of green area (vertically and horizontally)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also add `display: flex` on  `main` and remove `flex-grow: 1` from item.

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #ddd;
}
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
header,
footer {
  background-color: #abc
}
main {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: #bada55;
  display: flex;
}
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: red;
}
p {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<header>HEADER</header>
<main>

  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="item">
      <p>This should be centered both VERTICALLY & HORIZONTALLY.</p>
    </div>
  </div>

</main>
<footer>FOOTER</footer>
```

Answer (score 1):

Added

```
 main {
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      background-color: red;
    }
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #ddd;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

header,
footer {
  background-color: #abc
}

main {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: #bada55;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: red;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.item {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

p {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<header>HEADER</header>
<main>

  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="item">
      <p>This should be centered both VERTICALLY & HORIZONTALLY.</p>
    </div>
  </div>

</main>
<footer>FOOTER</footer>
```